# Power Strip/Extension Cord on TV stand

Tags: safety, circuit-breaker, receptacle, extension-cord

I have a question. I have a TV stand with a capacity of 80 lb., and on it a TV that weighs ~50lb. On the wall directly behind my TV, I have two electrical outlets. On the floor, I have a surge protector connected to one of the sockets. I have a single shelf about 4 feet above the TV stand where I would like to put a projector.

The length of the projector's power cord is only 5 feet, so I can't connect it to the surge protector or one of the 2 outlets. However, the 2 outlets allow for 2 surge protectors/power strips/extension cords etc. I thought of a few possible options and would like to know which one is the best.

1. Extend the length of the power cord (seems difficult, might void warranty)
2. Place a power strip on the TV stand and connect the power cord to it (safe?)
3. Place a power strip on a wall and connect the power cord to it. (safe?)

The rating for the circuit breaker says 125A Maximum and 120/240V. If circuits are only supposed to hold 15A, then mine seems to have a much higher capacity. Even if it only holds 15A, with the devices I have, connecting multiple power strips/extension cords will use far less power than 15A. Overloading the circuit is impossible.

My worry is that by placing a power cord on a TV stand or wall, it will overheat. Is it really safe and I have nothing to worry about?

Comment: It's very unlikely you have a 125A circuit breaker in your power strip or feeding an outlet. Please check and correct this.

Answer (score 3):

Most electrical equipment sold in the US, including power strips and surge protectors, are rated by Underwriters' Laboratories (UL) as being safe for normal use in residential settings. Power cords and stirps are intended to be placed on various surfaces without danger. If a power strip were tightly enclosed with no opportunity for ventilation, this *might* create an unsafe situation. Obviously, overloading a power strip or outlet is risky.

Your suggestion of placing a cord or power strip on a TV stand and using it to supply less than the rated amperage is well within the intended uses and should pose no risk.

Extension cords and power strips are not intended to permamently replace properly located outlets. However, many power strip approved by UL include mounting holes on the back for attaching to walls or carts. If this is carefully done, is not likely to be damaged or too tightly enclosed and is not overloaded, it should pose no problem.

It is possible that local laws or building or lease rules may limit some uses.

Answer (score 2):

Most surge protectors I've seen have these keyhole looking recesses on the back. These are used for surface mounting. You drive two screws into the surface you want to mount the power strip on and slide the power strip over them. There's a tip for making a template to [mount power strips to walls](http://tombuildsstuff.blogspot.com/2014/03/organizing-cable-clutter.html) that involves placing screws in the holes and pressing a sheet of paper over them.

I've mounted power strips to tv stands and other furniture as well as walls. I don't know of anything that forbids the practice and the fact that the devices contain mounting holes implies that you can do it.

Comment: If you're really concerned about heat, you could use spacers/standoffs to allow air to flow completely around the unit.